# Problems with Excel - Is a third party tampering with my computer?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, tampering

The following codes did not work for me, today. I think somebody is tampering with my computer. I wonder, how this could be duplicated, or is there an error with my code:

```vb
'number of rows for a certain column:
dim c as integer
c = WorksheetFunction.counta(columns("A:A"))
'get a value
c = range("A1")
```

Additional:
My code is a homework assignment, "Monte Carlo Simulation". It basically changes the costs of a list of items used to bake cookies and is using different types of distributions (uniform, normal, discrete) to do so. Excel exhausted its resources, because of an ill-formed loop with circular referencing - so the error message). I restarted Excel repeatedly. Eventually, I used original codes, which were provided by the Professor, and step by step re-inserted functions and procedures I already had coded, in order to find out how I had caused the Excel error message with my coding efforts. I ended up with 1000 of the "Monte-Carlo-Simulations" in 1 minute, rather than 30 minutes, observed before. The codes I provided I consider basic, but I am not able to resolve the issue, even if I copy old codes into my VBA modules. How could I avoid that an i.e. third party can tamper with my computer?

Added on July 20, 2021
This code uses the controls collection in order to obtain values of data on a form. You need form with two text fields which should have i.e. have double value content. So the controls collection is not working, since today.

i.e. `txtPerc1` and `txt1`
and then the function will return a value along with the discrete distribution.
The controls lines are commented out because I receive the error "sub or function not defined. I checked the name of the field and it was okay.

```vb
'sample call:
'discreteDistribtion("Hallo", 3)
' So I have six fields named:
' halloPerc1, halloPerc2, halloPerc3 and hallo1, hallo2, and hallo3
' the function takes here "hallo" and generates the names Hallo1, Hallo2, Hallo3 and halloPerc1, halloPerc2, and halloPerc3
' the function takes the value of hallo1, hallo2, or hallo3, each of these fields having doubles as content.
' According to the logic, hallo1, hallo2 or hallo3 values are returned!
' The code does not work on my computer, when I uncomment the controls code, it worked the weeks before.

Function discreteDistribution(strCtrl As String, iEnd As Integer, Optional iStart As Integer = 1)
    Dim i As Integer, sum As Double, r As Double, strTemp As String
    sum = 0
    r = Rnd
    discreteDistribution = 0
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        strTemp = strCtrl & "Perc" & i
        ''''''sum = sum + Controls(strTemp).Value
        If r < sum Then
            strTemp = strCtrl & i
        ''''''    discreteDistribution = Controls(strTemp)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

I added a second userform to my work book on a separate sheet and the following code is working:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 1 To 10
        Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

This code fills a bunch of textboxes with telephone numbers collected on a spread sheet. Still, I was not able to get my original code to work.

The code, recognized as faulty by Excel, highlighting the location, for the error shown in the previous image:
[image]

Comment: What is the error message?  What is the value of `i`?  Are you aware that an integer can only have a value of up to `32,767` and if assigned values greater than that will throw an overflow error?

Comment: yes, i am aware of that. thank you. The range examined here is A1:A9

Comment: Are you planning to supply sufficient information so someone can reproduce your problem?  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The image attached, shows code, which at the time was not working. I added additional code, which requires you to create a form with six fields. Please try this out on your computer. My bet is that this would work for you.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Luuk I already uploaded images. I thought that was not suitable for Ron Rosenfeld, so I provided some code in my amended question.

Answer (score 0):

Though not the entire question is answered here, my today's problem is resolved. The controls collection is a property of the user form. So in order to call this collection from within a module, it needs to know the form it is related to. So rather than calling **controls("Name of Control") = ...** the call must be: **form.controls("Name of Control")** and then the code works.

Thank you to everybody who replied to my request for encouragement.